# gnuplot: Calculate a square root

Tags: gnuplot

when I type `sqrt(4)` I get

`^`
`invalid command`

how do I calculate the square root of a positive real number with gnuplot?

Comment: You should probably be using a tool designed for calculations such as `bc` or `dc`. The `sqrt()` function in `gnuplot` is intended for manipulating data under the plot command, not as a command in-and-of itself.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? `sqrt(4)` on its own is an invalid gnuplot command - but (for example) `plot sqrt(4)` should be valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `gnuplot` to show you the result of a square root, then use the `print()` function in any of these ways:

• `> print(sqrt(4));`

or

• `> a=sqrt(4);print(a);`

or

• `> a=4;print(sqrt(a));`